# Extract all Capital Words from List (Python3)

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract all capital movies from a list that I have scraped:
I am trying to use regex to do so

```
wikis = ["http://www.boxofficemojo.com/daily/chart/"]
for wiki in wikis:
    website = requests.get(wiki)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, "lxml")
    text = ''.join([element.text for element in soup.body.find_all(lambda tag: tag != 'script', recursive=False)])
    new =  re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z \n]','',text)
    caps = re.findall('([A-Z]+(?=\s[A-Z]+)(?:\s[A-Z]+)+)', new)
```

However, my output is appending an extra capital letter at the end of my movies

```
'BEASTS OF NO NATIONN'
'EVEREST U'
'THE MARTIANF'
```

Not sure why but I know it has something to do with my regex code:

```
caps = re.findall('([A-Z]+(?=\s[A-Z]+)(?:\s[A-Z]+)+)', new)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it have to with a regex? `all(char.isupper() for char in title)` should do the trick

Comment: I think it has to do with the string formatting of new. Since you used re.sub to replace everything that isnt a new line,letter, or space, then the first letter of the producer (ie, warner bros, fox, etc) is being included in the string.

Comment: What if you use a space to join elements instead? `text = ' '.join(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead.

```
caps = re.findall('([A-Z]+(?:(?!\s?[A-Z][a-z])\s?[A-Z])+)', new)
```

to make sure that the the next word is not just a capitalized word. I can't check this so I dont know for sure if it will work.

EDIT:

I apologize, the last one made no sense once I actually thought about it. It has been changed to one that should work

Comment: Same Issue with the extra capital when I run this

Comment: check the edit, according to Debuggex, this worked on sample date of 'BEASTS OF NO NATIONNw'
'EVEREST Univ'
'THE MARTIANFos'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `soup.body.find_all(lambda tag: tag != 'script', recursive=False)` only returns 3 elements. The third appears to be all of the text in the body with all tags stripped out. So your movie title is right up against your studio name, like this: THE MARTIANFox. So grabbing the caps from that would give you THE MARTIANF.

Also, just looking for caps you will miss things like MISSION: IMPOSSIBLE - ROGUE NATION because of the non-alpha characters.

How about this instead?

```
wikis = ["http://www.boxofficemojo.com/daily/chart/"]
for wiki in wikis:
    website = requests.get(wiki)
    caps = re.findall("<a href=\"/movies[^>]*>([^<a-z]*)</a>", website.content)
```

Each movie is inside an link that points to /movies, so that's an easy way to find them. `<a href=\"movies[^>]*>` will match the opening anchor tag, `([^<a-z]*)` will match a string without lowercase characters inside the anchor tag (the movie title), and then `</a>` to close it out.